# Doing two queries on a single php throws second to not being fetchable

Tags: php, html, mysql

I'm trying to fill various html selects with their respective information. For that I feel the right way is to make a query for each of them. I do the first query with this php tag to fill the first `select` like this:

```
<?php 
$sql = "call mydb.getPositions();";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
    echo "<option>".$row[0]."</option>";
}
?>
```

That's it. Simple. It works. The function `getPositions()` is a `select`. But when I tried to fill the next select/combobox with it's own query, it started throwing this error:

> Fatal error:  Call to a member function fetch_row() on a non-object in file.php in line 200

I searched for a lot of reasons for a mistake like typos in the query or fetching rows from a `delete` query.
But then to discard any mistake of those, I decided to copy the exact same php tag one after the other. So, if the first works, why wouldn't the second work? So there I saw that I was receiving the exact same mistake. What am I missing? I tried to close the `$result`, with no success.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT.
When I said "I decided to copy the exact same php tag one after the other" I really meant that like:

```
<?php 
$sql = "call mydb.getPositions();";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
    echo "<option>".$row[0]."</option>";
}
?>
<?php 
$sql = "call mydb.getPositions();";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

//It throws the error down here
while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
    echo "<option>".$row[0]."</option>";
}
?>
```

And this throws the same error described before.

EDIT2.
The procedure is this:

```
CREATE DEFINER=`mainSoccer`@`%` PROCEDURE `getPositions`()
BEGIN
    Select namePosition from mydb.Position;
END
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like your question is actually: how do I run the same MySQL query twice in a php script? If so, here's the answer:

```
<?php
$sql = "Select namePosition from mydb.Position;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
    echo "<option>".$row[0]."</option>";
}
?>
<!-- presumably you have other code in between here -->
<?php
$sql = "Select namePosition from mydb.Position;";
$result = $conn->query($sql);

while($row = $result->fetch_row()){
    echo "<option>".$row[0]."</option>";
}
?>
```

And in your comment to my original answer below, you asked "Why shouldn't I be creating a MySQL procedure?" Two answers:

1. Your initial code is *creating* the same procedure twice. That is surely throwing an error at the MySQL level. Generally one *creates* the procedure once for permanent re-use directly in your server, so that many different scripts can them simply *invoke* (not create) that procedure at any time.
2. You should use MySQL procedures for complex, large MySQL operations that have performance issues that can gain efficiency as a pre-compiled procedure. Your query here is very simple and does not call for a MySQL procedure.

Hope this helps.

Comment: I'm sorry for late answer. Your answer was kinda the solution. I still don't know how to execute a MySQL function, but as my project was kinda small, I just put the function body in the $sql (select * from....) and manually executed the query each time a "function" needed to be called. Thanks anyway.

Answer (score 0):

Since you only posted your code that works, but not the code that doesn't work, you can't get specific help.

But I can tell you that the error you quote "Fatal error: Call to a member function fetch_row() on a non-object in file.php in line 200" is typically caused when you write invalid SQL.

First confirm that the SQL you are attempting runs on its own as raw SQL, for example in phpMyAdmin.

Comment: I'm sorry. I added an edit to make more explicit the part of the code that doesn't work.

Comment: So the next question is what is going on inside your mysterious SQL "call mydb.getPositions()" - perhaps the logic in that getPositions() code explains that you can't call it again in this context? =

Comment: I can tell you that the problem is not in your php code, it's in your MySQL procedure, or the fact that you are attempting to run that MySQL twice during the same connection. My advice above to run these queries directly in MySQL is still good. Prove it works in MySQL (running it twice in immediate succession) before trying it in a php script.

Comment: Now I'm wondering if you are missing a basic concept of php + MySQL work? Are you perhaps simply trying to run the query "Select namePosition from mydb.Position;" twice? If so, you should not be creating a MySQL procedure for that. Instead simply run the query from php directly. If this is what you're trying to do, revise your question and I'll answer that.

Comment: It worked that last way. But I was trying to use a procedure for good programming practices. Why shouldn't I be creating a MySQL procedure?